# fetching x days ahead of current date record by comparing specific date from column of table

Tags: php, mysql

[apologies in advance for my english]

i have a column in my database table event_start_date (user input datetime) and my **requirement** is to get data of x days ahead of current datetime. and value of event_start_date in the resulting record should be greater than or equal to NOW() (current date time)

```
`event_start_date >= NOW()`  (using php or mysql)
```

this is what i have done so far (zend in magento):

> `$sql = $read->select()
>   ->from(array('e' => 'my_table'));`
>
> `$where = "e.event_start_date = DATE(DATE_ADD(e.event_start_date,
>   INTERVAL x DAY))";`
>
> `$sql->where($where);`
>
> `echo $sql->__toString();exit;` // this results in
>
> `SELECT`e`.* FROM 'my_table' AS 'e' WHERE (e.event_start_date =
>   DATE(DATE_ADD(e.event_start_date, INTERVAL x DAY)))`

another i used is

> `SELECT`e`.* FROM 'my_table' AS 'e' WHERE 
>   DATEDIFF(e.event_start_date,DATE(DATE_ADD(e.event_start_date, INTERVAL
>   {$x} DAY)));`

both output one row if x = 1 only. what would be the solution? i am kinda stuck.

appreciate your help a lot.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE event_start_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Your statement:

```
DATEDIFF(e.event_start_date,DATE(DATE_ADD(e.event_start_date, INTERVAL {$x} DAY)));
```

actually means: "where start_date + 3 days is higher than start_date"
and it does not make much sense

Comment: you are write i was trying being a smart a** :D but your solution worked i am gonna accept your answer as soon as it allows me. thanks